# In bash, see is USB is mounted and, if so, replace files

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I have JS experience and a little Python, but no bash whatsoever.

I need to see if a USB drive is mounted and, if so, copy the files from the usb to a directory.

I want to copy this directory in its entirety, **removing old files**. So, if the original filesystem was:

```
-- dir
---- file.txt
---- file2.txt
```

and now it is

```
-- dir
---- foo.txt
```

I want the final directory to be like the second block. If I just `cp` it becomes:

```
-- dir
---- foo.txt
---- file.txt
---- file2.txt
```

So, to do ALL that, what I am doing now is: I have a "DO-NOT-DELETE.txt" file in my usb

```sh
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /files &
file="/files/DO-NOT-DELETE.txt"
if [ -e $file ]
then
  sudo rm -rf /home/pi/poem-printer/files
  sudo cp -r /files /home/pi/poem-printer
fi
```

This works but I think it's suboptimal.

(I'm doing all this in `rc.local` in a raspberry pi running Raspbian)

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Why do you run `mount` in the background? The rest may run before the device is finished mounting.

Comment: Use rsync with --delete flag. Check out this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476041/how-do-i-make-rsync-delete-files-that-have-been-deleted-from-the-source-folder). And you probably want to remove the trailing `&` in the first line as Barmar pointed out.

Comment: I didn't exactly know what the `&` did. I followed another tutorial to make it happen. I removed it and went to the `rsync` approach and it worked. Thanks @Barmar and @DerMaddi